# Nested XML search support in Sphinx?

Tags: xml, full-text-search, sphinx

Does Sphinx xmlpipe2 supports nested XML strcuture for search? For example, something like this.

```
<sphinx:document id="1234">
<attr1>some data</attr1>
<attr2>some more</attr2>
<tags>
    <tag id="23">One</tag>
    <tag id="24">Two</tag>
</tags>
<misc>some more info</misc>
</sphinx:document>
```

If not, what's the best possible approach for storing associated data in a search efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

In short no.

Should be able to

```
<tags>23,24</tags>
```

if you define tags as a Multi-Value-Attribute in the schema.

If want to be able to search them full-text, can put them in a normal field too

```
<tag_ids>23,24</tag_ids>
<tags>One,Two</tags>
```

Can also make tags a string attribute, so can get the values out. Just be sure to presort the tags by tag_id - as sphinx internally sorts the MVA into numeric order.

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter. But tags was just a simple example and the actual scenario is much more complex. A better analogy would be a listing, review and comments where a listing can have many reviews and each review can have many comments. If a search term matches anything from a listing, it's reviews and/or comments of reviews then listing should be returned in search. And search can be filtered on any of the column of those 3 entities. Does it make sense?

Comment: Its exactly the same. just like the tags example collapsed them down to a single string for a feild, do the same with your reviews, and comments. Sphinx indexes, are flat and non-hierarchical, anyway, so you need to 'flatten' the data at some point. Might as well be when generating your XML.

Comment: Thanks again, got your point. One last question though - is it possible to have multiple tags for same attribute instead of using MVA, e.g. 

`<review>One</review>
<review>Two</review>`

I have some fields as JSON and if I go MVA route, I need to club those fields as well. Consider this - I have a JSON field which stores 3 attributes, e.g. a, b and c in format {"a":x,"b":y,"c":z} and if there are 3 reviews then the value of a. b and c would be most likely different. How filtering on attributes (a, b and c) would work if I store them as MVA (I doubt even search would work if I club json fields)

Comment: first question, dont beleive so. second part, think would just need to create multiple fields (so the schema would have to enumerate all possible), eg fielda, fieldb and fieldc. Can miss out ones not needed on specific documents.

Comment: Hmm. Problem is I can't fix the XML schema since there can be n number of related reviews with each listing and m number of feedback on each review. I was hoping if I can define review and comment tags once in XML schema and then include all details each in a separate tag then it might work. But looks like that's not an option.

Comment: Correct. Anyway, looks like taking this to the sphinx forum, http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=12756 - which is better than SO for discussions anyway. The comments fields here are very limited